# strip images from get_the_content() removes also <p> tags

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, preg-replace

I'm trying to strip all images and the surrounding `<a>` tag from `get_the_content()` with this piece of code:

```
<?php
$content = get_the_content();
$postOutput = preg_replace(array('{<a[^>]*><img[^>]+.}','{></a>}'),'', $content);
echo $postOutput;
?>
```

That works fine, except there are no `<p>` tags around the paragraphs.
1. Is this normal when using `get_the_content()`?
2. and how could I add them to my result?
3. Or is my regex wrong?

Comment: WRONG WRONG WRONG. Don't use regexes to mangle html. You'll just end up ripping out any hair you've got left. Use [DOM](http://php.net/dom)

Comment: why dont you just use a strip_tags(get_the_content(), '<p>');  ?

Comment: [`get_the_content`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_content) does not run the `the_content` filters, one of which adds those `<p>` tags, so yes, that is normal.

Comment: @MarcB Okay thats wrong. I'm a total php noob. I've been looking around the web for solutions and this regex approach was what I found.

Comment: I'd like to know how to do this, as well as remove galleries shortcodes that show up

Comment: @JohnB I'm trying to remove all `<a><img src="blabla"></a>` maybe my questions is wrong. @s_ha_dum thanks. Thats good to know that the `<p>` tags are in fact not there.

Comment: @fabiantheblind: a lot of php "tips" you find on the web are crap (literally) or flat-out wrong. there's a LOT of misinformation out there. they may have worked for whoever posted them, in their own limited circumstances, but should never used as a general solution.

Comment: @MarcB thanks. And yes I'm loosing my hair while writing php. It's my first project with it. Coming from JavaScript it all feels pretty ugly . I'll try to rewrite my question and also take a look into DOM

Comment: I rewrote my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14878908/how-to-remove-all-images-with-and-without-sourrounding-links-from-the-content) and think this one is answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I will answer my own questions:

1. Yes it is normal that there are no `<p>` on `get_the_content()` thanks @s_ha_dum
2. To add the `<p>` I need to apply the content filter as [mentioned here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_content) (scroll down to "Alternative Usage").
3. The regex is not wrong but it is pretty dirty to regex the html. Thanks @MarcB

See the new question that lead to the following code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14878908/how-to-remove-all-images-with-and-without-sourrounding-links-from-the-content)

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML(get_the_content());
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$nodes = $xpath->query('//img|//a[img]');
foreach($nodes as $node) {
    $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
}
$no_image_content = $dom->saveHTML();
$no_image_content = apply_filters('the_content', $no_image_content);
$no_image_content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $no_image_content);
echo $no_image_content;
```