# How to remove all images with and without sourrounding links from the_content() on specific page template

Tags: php, wordpress, dom

I'm trying to strip all `<img>` with and without surrounding `<a>` tags from `the_content()` for a specific page template. I already found some solutions including `preg_replace` and using `get_the_content()` but when using `get_the_content()` there are no `<p>` surrounding the paragraphs.

How could I filter `the_content()` on a page template to remove all `<a><img></a>` and `<img>` tags?

I've been adviced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14878174/strip-images-from-get-the-content-removes-also-p-tags) not to use `preg_replace` for that but rather [DOM](http://php.net/dom).
Some push in the right direction would be great because I'm a PHP rookie.

Comment: push in the right direction: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=remove+html+user%3A208809

Comment: The Boilerplate code to delete an Element with DOM is always the same. You can find enough examples in the link above. The only thing that varies is how you get the elements. To get all the a elements with an image child you use `//a[img]`. To get all the images you `//img`. You can combine these two by putting `|` between them.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon I will look into the examples above and report back when I got something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I will answer my own question, but first thanks to [Gordon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/208809/gordon) for pushing me into the right direction. My result is based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3804339/replace-ul-tags-with-specific-class/3804508#3804508) question here on stackoverflow.

It uses [`DOM`](http://php.net/dom) and not `preg_replace()` like I saw it on many examples.
One thing to mention is that I need to use `get_the_content()` instead of `the_content()` because `the_content()` echos a filtered result. But in the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_content) is a hint how to filter `get_the_content()` to achieve the same output as `the_content()`.

Here is the code that does what I want:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML(get_the_content());
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$nodes = $xpath->query('//img|//a[img]');
foreach($nodes as $node) {
    $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
}
$no_image_content = $dom->saveHTML();
$no_image_content = apply_filters('the_content', $no_image_content);
$no_image_content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $no_image_content);
echo $no_image_content;
```